# Complexity and length

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, computational-complexity

Suppose we define continuous piecewise linear functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ using your favorite programming language, or by finite automata, or by any other suitable machine. Define the complexity $H(f)$ as the length of the shortest program describing the function.

The naive question is: is the length of the graph of $f$ is big if $H(f)$ is big? The answer to the naive question is obviously negative: for example for any random binary sequence one can construct a function which is piecewise $\vee$ or $\wedge$ of rapidly decreasing height.

The question: does a *typical* function graph's length has a nontrivial lower boundary in terms of $H$? *Typical* can be substituted with whatever notion of *biggness*.

To state something precise (one of the ways):
Is there an inequality $length(f)> F(H(f))$ with $F\to\infty$ with $H\to \infty$ which holds for all $f$ from a class of functions $U$ whose intersection with the set of all functions of complexity $<N$ has cardinality not less than $C\cdot (\text{number of all functions of complexity}<N) $ for some fixed constant $0<C<1$ for all $N$.

In other words, if a typical continuous piecewise function defined by a very complicated program (that can't be simplified) looks something like a Brownian motion and has a very long graph. Or rather, if a random program of length $N$ defining a continuous piecewise affine function, gives a long function?